# A question in a theorem of Hom in modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

While studying algebra from Thomas Hungerford I have a question in proof of a theorem on page 200 of Text.

It's image :

[image]

> Question is in 2nd line of proof : How can author write $\bar \theta (f) = f\theta$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f\in\text{Hom}(B,D)$; it is a homomorphism from $B$ to $D$. Also $\theta$ is a homomorphism from $A$ to $B$. Their composite $f\theta=f\circ\theta$
is a homomorphism from $A$ to $D$: $f\theta\in\text{Hom}(A,D)$. By definition,
$\bar\theta$ is the map taking $f$ to $f\theta$: $\bar\theta(f)=f\theta$.

Answer (score 2):

Because that's what $\overline \theta$ is: the map that sends every homomorphism $f$ to $f\theta:=f\circ \theta$.